# Map<String, Integer> getting rounded int percentage

Tags: java

I have a `Map<String, Integer>` and an integer named globalValue. My goal is to replace values in map with percentage of globalValue, eg; (value1/globalValue)*100 and round the final number.

I have tried doing division directly in the map (which resulted in 0) and also trying to convert my integers to double both in the map and outside the map (both resulted in type mismatch).

```
public Map<String, Integer> analyse() {
    int globalValue = 0;
    Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].getTime() != null) {
            globalValue = globalValue + array[i].getValue();
            if (m.containsKey(array[i].getTime())) {
                m.put(array[i].getTime(), m.get(array[i].getTime()) + array[i].getValue());
            } else {
                m.put(array[i].getTime(), array[i].getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Why not make your map of `Double` instead of `Integer`?

Comment: Shed some details on your `array`

Comment: there is no `(value1/globalValue)*100` division logic in code, can you explain what exactly you need? either division logic? or rephrase the above code?

Comment: As GBlodgett suggested use a Double instead or try casting the value `(Integer)`?

Comment: "I have tried doing division directly in the map (which resulted in 0)" most likely because you're performing integer division. make one of the operands a double. nevertheless, your current code doesn't show any of that logic....

Comment: @GBlodgett return type has to be integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be much simpler using the Stream API. You also need to use `double` or `Double` to avoid rounding all values down to 0.

```
public Map<String, Double> analyse() {
    double sum = Stream.of(array).mapToDouble(d -> d.getValue()).sum();
    return Stream.of(array)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getTime(),
                    Collectors.summingDouble(t -> t.getValue() * 100.0 / sum)));
}
```

Why does this happen with `int` values?

[Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Most children learn integer division in primary school but seem to forget all about it once we learn decimals.

To return `Integer` percentages without too much loos of precision.

```
public Map<String, Integer> analyse() {
    long sum = Stream.of(array).mapToLong(d -> d.getValue()).sum();
    Map<String, Long> map = Stream.of(array)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getTime(),
                    Collectors.summingLong(t -> t.getValue())));
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> (int) Math.round(100.0 * e.getValue() / sum)));
}
```

This handles the situation where many small values can add up to 1%.

Comment: well, my return type has to be integer.

Comment: @J.Doe then return an integer.. just don't do the calculation with integers

Comment: @J.Doe I have added a solution which calculates an Integer reducing the loss of precision.

Comment: @PeterLawrey also the last `100` should be `100.0` right?

Comment: @xtratic it depends on whether an overflow of `100 * long` or a loss of precision from `100.0 * long` is more likely.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ahh good point. I'd thought you'd just missed it while doing your edits. I didn't read carefully enough, my bad.

Comment: @xtratic that is why I used longs for calculations to avoid overflows.

Comment: @PeterLawrey actually without `100.0` then `100 * e.getValue() / sum` will truncate to a `long` and `Math.round` will essentially do nothing, right? I simplified to this, eliminating the intermediate map: `long sum = Stream.of(array).mapToLong(o -> o.getValue()).sum();   Map<String, Number> m = Stream.of(array).collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getTime(), o -> Math.round(100d * o.getValue() / sum)));`

Comment: @xtratic good point, in the first example `sum` as ` double` but I dropped it in the second case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yep, I figured it was just an error in the copy pasting and editing.

Comment: Why the intermediate map though?